# What is the correct way to access a workspace file in databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

My databricks runtime version is 10.4 LTS. I am trying to access a workspace file using `open()` method from python. I tried with multiple different ways, but they all failed.

Suppose my workspace file path is `/Workspace/Users/<user-email>/my_result.json`, I tried the following paths:

- without any prefix, `/Workspace/Users/<user-email>/my_result.json`: failed
- adding `/dbfs`, `/dbfs/Workspace/Users/<user-email>/my_result.json`: failed
- adding `/file`, `/file/Workspace/Users/<user-email>/my_result.json`: failed

Is my path format wrong, or it is just we can't access files under workspace using the `open()` method from Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these documentations ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/share-code), [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/workspace/workspace-assets)), the workspace files or assets are available for Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above.

> With Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above, you can create and manage source code files in the Azure Databricks workspace, and then import these files into your notebooks as needed.

Using the path without a prefix is the correct method. It works fine in Runtime 11.2 and above.

```
file_path = "/Workspace/Users/xxx@yyy.com/outdata.json"

try:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        print(content)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

Output:

[image]

Therefore, you need to use Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above, or upload your `.json` file into `dbfs`. When opening the file, prefix the path with `/dbfs/path_to_file/`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What is the databricks runtime version that you are running your code in the screenshot?

Comment: Mine is 13.3. I have checked with 10.4, it just gives no such file or directory. You can check by listing folders itself. `%fs ls file:/Workspace/`. You will find `Users` folder in 11.2 and above.